# Is it possible to attach one NetStream to several videoDisplays?

Tags: apache-flex, netstream

I'm working on simple videochat app with Adobe FMS 4.5. Everything works fine except one thing: I have small videoDisplay for each connected client and one main display. So user can choose his main interlocutor. When i'm trying to attach netStream to main display from small one, streaming on small one stops. Is there way to play one netStream to several displays at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I recall, you can only attach one NetStream object at a time.  There is a solution possible, however, I would like for you to rethink about your UX because you have "duplicate information" being shown (a large display, and a small display, with the same data) and you're using more space than needed as well.  From a design standpoint, this isn't very logical and I would recommend that you only have one working at a time while "removing" the small one when the large one is active.

However, if you're hard set in your ways, you could simply duplicate the bitmap information over from the large one to the small one (to prevent loss of resolution from doing it the other way around.  You'll have to research this part and figure it how it can work with your system, but it's a fairly simple concept: you take a 'screenshot' (the pixels of the current video) and use that data to be displayed somewhere else.

Comment: I chose the first way, but thanks for this trick with bitmap.